# How to remove all element except one?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I would like to remove all element from my canva except the one on which I click. 
I create a set, put all element inside and remove the set :

```
button.click(function () {
    var to_remove = paper.set();    
    paper.forEach(function (el) {
        to_remove.push(el);
    });         
    to_remove.remove();
});
```

But i don't success to test if my element is my button or not.

Axel

Comment: try adding in a `return true;` below the `el.remove();`

Comment: *"But, It remove only one element (and when i click again, it remove the next one)..."* That seems very strange, `forEach` should loop through the entire contents of `paper` (assuming `paper` is an array).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was thinking if el.remove() were to return false for some reason, then forEach will break rather than continuing.  I haven't got Raphael source open at moment but I will look into this later.

Comment: @JonTaylor: No, because the OP isn't *returning* the result of `el.remove()`, and even if it did, [`forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) doesn't care about the return value of the iterator function. (For that, you need one of the others, like [`some`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17).)

Comment: I've try to add return true; below the el.remove(); but it doesn't work. It still remove one element by one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder isn't the last function call returned implicitly?  (This was just a guess), forEach does care about the return value of the callback function **If callback function returns false it will stop loop running.** Taken from their documentation.  `forEach` is a Raphael Paper prototype function.

Comment: @JonTaylor: No, the result of the last function is not returned implicitly; that would be chaos. :-) If a function doesn't explicitly use `return someValue`, the result of calling it is `undefined`. You're quite right about `forEach`, though, I was thining of JavaScript's, but this is clearly Raphael's, which is different.

Comment: I success by adding all element into a Set value and remove this Set.

Comment: But i didn't know how i can test if my element is my button or not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ha true, thinking about it that makes sense.  It's because Im working with grails at the moment and not explicitly writing return. axel585  It's odd you couldn't get it working on the paper but glad you got it working by other means.  It would be worth putting this as an answer for others to see.

Comment: Yes, but i can't answer my own question... because i'm a newbie :-) So, i change my question, but it's a quiet crappy...

Comment: @axel584: You can answer your own question after the time limit, it should have told you that when preventing the answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But did you know how can i test if "el" is my "button" element ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cache your clicked element and compare it during the loop.

```
button.click(function() {
    var clickedEl = this,
        toRemove = paper.set();

    paper.forEach(function(el) {
        if (el !== clickedEl) {
            toRemove.push(el);
        }
    });

    toRemove.remove();
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yRNNe/